# How to set up azure keyvault for spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

There was some dependency incompatibility occurring because we were using an older version of azure keyvault (azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter 2.2.1) but it got updated and we are upgrading it to azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets 4.0.0. Now the keyvault isn't being connected maybe because the application.yml keyvault config is in the wrong syntax.

This is what was there before when it was working with the 2.2.1 version:

```
azure:
  keyvault:
    uri: ${uri}
    client-id: ${clientId}
    client-key: ${clientKey}
    token-acquire-timeout-seconds: 120
```

This is how we are trying now but it isn't connecting.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          property-sources:
            uri: ${uri}
            client-id: ${clientId}
            client-key: ${clientKey}
            token-acquire-timeout-seconds: 120
```

What is the correct syntax for this azure keyvault version configuration??

Comment: check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#add-key-vault-configuration-to-the-app) to know about adding Key Vault configuration to the app.

Answer (score 1):

not working for me and getting below error..
Caused by: com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It should most probably look like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          property-sources[0]:
            endpoint: ${uri}
            credential:
              client-id: ${clientId}
              client-secret: ${clientKey}
```

From the migration guide from 3.x.x to 4.x ([direct link](https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/4.2.0/reference/html/appendix.html#configuration-spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets)):

| Legacy properties | Modern properties |
| --- | --- |
| azure.keyvault.case-sensitive-keys | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].case-sensitive |
| azure.keyvault.certificate-password | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].credential.client-certificate-password |
| azure.keyvault.certificate-path | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].credential.client-certificate-path |
| azure.keyvault.client-id | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].credential.client-id |
| azure.keyvault.client-key | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].credential.client-secret |
| azure.keyvault.enabled | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.enabled and spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-source-enabled |
| azure.keyvault.refresh-interval | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].refresh-interval |
| azure.keyvault.secret-keys | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].secret-keys |
| azure.keyvault.tenant-id | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].profile.tenant-id |
| azure.keyvault.uri | spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[n].endpoint |